# What's the energy density of longitudinal wave in plasma?

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics

For longitudinal wave, the magnetic and displacement fields are zero, then according to the common formula (by which I mean (**D**$\cdot$**E**$^*$+**B**$\cdot$**H**$^*$)/2) for the energy density of electromagnetic field longitudinal wave has zero energy density. Apparently it must carry certain energy. So my question is how to reconcile the contradiction. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by *common formula*, could you specify that ?

Comment: @Alf I've edited the question to indicate which formula I meant. Thanks!

Comment: just to understand you correctly: are you saying that B=0 and D=0 for longitudinal waves in a plasma? If it is a purely longitudinal wave, it is an electrostatic wave and there is no electromagnetic field, as you said; if it is partly longitudinal, there is also an electromagnetic field. Note that in the plasma, the oscillating currents induced by the oscillating electric fields also carries energy.

Comment: Yes, you understand my question correctly. Then in case of pure longitudinal wave, how do we calculate its energy density or total energy? With no energy stored in electromagnetic field, we are only left with kinetic and potential energies of electrons, which is basically the energy carried by oscillating currents as you said. Am I right?